# want to join the array values to textarea

Tags: javascript

I have array in javascript ,Now I want to join the array values to textarea but I want to append + or - to each number like that -3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6 . Can anyone help me please?

```
      var array=[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
      $("#data").val(array.join("\n")); 

     </body>
     <textarea id="data"></textarea>
     </body>
```

Comment: so I think `-` is already there you just want to add `+` to numbers after `0`.

Comment: Yes,but How can I do that?

Comment: Before you join them, you have to convert them to strings and append a + or -. So make a loop to do that and store it in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` to apply a function to each array element and return their results.

```
$("#data").val(array.map(function(x) {
    return x > 0 ? '+'+x : x.toString();
}).join("\n"));
```